# Unable to connect to wifi Dell D820 Ubuntu

Tags: wireless, dell, broadcom

Hello can somebody help me? 
I'm new with Linux.I installed the broadcom drivers but I still can't connect
I ran the wireless info script

http://paste.ubuntu.com/23738491/

Thnx Hurnen

Comment: Paste the script results at paste.ubuntu.com and add the URL to your question

Comment: @ Jeremy31
Thnx
http://paste.ubuntu.com/23738491/

Answer (score 0):

Please note that your mode is shown as Master in `iwconfig`. You also have a 10.42.0.1 IP address. That suggests that you have used the utility to *Create New Wi-Fi Network*. This is for computer-to-computer connections and not what you want. You want to make a computer-to-router connection.

Please remove all such settings by clicking the Network Manager icon and editing connections. Also, make sure that, under Wi-Fi, the mode is *Client* and under IPv4 settings, the mode is set to *DHCP*.

Reboot and let us hear your report.

I recommend that your regulatory domain be set explicitly. Check yours:

```
sudo iw reg get
```

If you get 00, that is a one-size-maybe-fits-all setting. Find yours here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2 Then set it temporarily:

```
sudo iw reg set IS
```

Of course, substitute your country code if not Iceland. Set it permanently:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/default/crda
```

Use nano or kate or leafpad if you don't have the text editor gedit.

Change the last line to read:

```
REGDOMAIN=IS
```

Proofread carefully, save and close the text editor.

Network Manager will default to ethernet if it is available as it is generally more secure and faster. Please detach the ethernet and try to connect. If you are unable to connect, let us see another paste:

```
dmesg | grep -e b43 -e wlan | tail -n20
```

In the paste you supplied, we see repeats of this:

```
denied association (code=27)
```

Please check the settings in the router. WPA2-AES is preferred; not any WPA and WPA2 mixed mode and certainly not TKIP. Second, if your router is capable of N speeds, you may have better connectivity with a channel width of 20 MHz in the 2.4 GHz band instead of automatic 20/40 MHz, although it is likely to affect N speeds. I also have better luck with a fixed channel, either 1, 6 or 11, rather than automatic channel selection. Also, be certain the router is not set to use N speeds only; auto B, G and N is preferred. After making these changes, reboot the router.

Possible reference: https://forums.kali.org/showthread.php?29952-Will-not-associate-when-AP-is-802-11n-only

Comment: Thnx for youre time and reaction
I think I cleaned up the mess I made
But no connection yet
http://paste.ubuntu.com/23739629/

Comment: Please see my edit above in a few moments.

Comment: REGDOMAIN=NL
new paste:
http://paste.ubuntu.com/23739847/

Comment: Please see my edit above in a few minutes.

Comment: Problem solved with a workaround
I have connected an old  FritzBox 7360 to my Ubee EVW 3226 router 
and with the FritzBox the wifi works fine

Thank you for your help!